# Pandas: Feeding index values to apply

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having problems when trying to use apply on the result of a groupby operation.

I have the following 2 dataframes:

```
>>> df1.head()
         col1  col2  col3
id1                      
2001991   0.0     0     0
1501102   3.0     1     1
1701072   0.0     0     0
2001022   0.1    20    50
2001212   3.0     2     4
>>> df2.head()
     id2  value      id1
0  24400   6.28  2001022
1  24400   3.40  2001011
2  24037  12.30  2002011
3  24037   3.00  2001382
4  24037  20.00  1701071
```

I first did a groupby and a sum to df2:

```
>>> df2 = df2.groupby(['id2', 'id1']).sum()
>>> df2.head()
              value
id2 id1            
81  1701071   49.94
88  1701071  759.22
    2001011   73.26
    2001382  199.70
    2003071   25.00
```

And I now would like to use apply, but I need to feed it id1, which is part of the index, so I get an error when I try to do the following:

```
df2['new'] = df2.apply(lambda row: min(row['value'], df1.loc[row['id1'], 'col1']), axis=1)
```

What's the right way of doing this?

[BTW, I have also tried to merge df1 and df2 in one table (so that each row in df2 has a field with the corresponding col1, col2 and col3 from df1), but when I do the groupby and sum() it aggregates col1, col2 and col3 values (which I don't want)]

Comment: You can reset the index `df2.reset_index(level='id1'`), then it will be an ordinary column. Or provide `as_index=False` to the groupby call.

Comment: @joris I think that's a really good answer. Worth putting in an answer box, I think.

Comment: @joris: Thanks, as_index=False is a good solution for me. (Since you answered as a comment I can't vote you up)

Comment: @Armando I put it in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the index, then it will be an ordinary column:

```
df2.reset_index(level='id1')
```

Or provide `as_index=False` to the groupby call:

```
df2.groupby(['id2', 'id1'], as_index=False).sum()
```